# Where are the the more specific CSS overflow tags? Can I add them?

Tags: discussion

I'll be able to create tags on Stack Overflow soonish. So, before I attempt to create these tags at some point in the future: [overflow-x](/questions/tagged/overflow-x), [overflow-y](/questions/tagged/overflow-y)

I'll first ask meta why they don't exist now and what can I expect to happen when/if I create them? Should I create them? Why or why not?

For reference, I was searching for an answer to a particular problem and arrived at this question/answer.
[CSS overflow-y:visible, overflow-x:scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209545/css-overflow-yvisible-overflow-xscroll)

Related? [Can tags be too specific?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100062/can-tags-be-too-specific)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't exist because they don't meet the requirements for tags, specifically, the "A tag must be able to stand alone in a question" requirement. [overflow-x](/questions/tagged/overflow-x) and [overflow-y](/questions/tagged/overflow-y) cannot exist in a question without the [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag applied as well. Hence it shouldn't be created.