# How should new tags be created?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I created the [preg-grep](/questions/tagged/preg-grep) tag in some of my questions. Later, I encountered another question which  was about the `preg_grep` function, but the tag was unavailable already.

I thought it was because I didn't fill out the tag wiki, so I created the tag again, filled out the info and tagged three questions which should have that tag. Later, the tag was removed by a moderator, so I guess something was wrong.

If so, I would expect some notice, but nothing happened. I didn't find anything in FAQ, about and privileges sections. Could someone please explain why my action was not correct?

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100062/can-tags-be-too-specific) a while ago, but coming from the "other side" (i.e. asking about removing a tag that was a function name). There's no clear-cut directive on this AFAIK, it's a bit of a judgment call.

Comment: Minor note: It was not a moderator who deleted the tags. It was a [regular (and unsurprising) user](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15722405/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

If we start creating tags for every function in every programming language they won't be of any use very soon.

That is why the tag was removed from the questions by someone and if a tag is not used it will be deleted automatically. You are not getting notifications about changes for tags you created.

If a tag is meaningful it will stay after being creating (by adding to a question).

You could have used the tags [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and [php](/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: Yet, there are tags for some functions. When should be function promoted to tag? Are there any hard criteria, like at least 100 questions about it?

Comment: I'd say don't create new tags for functions at all.

Comment: What if the function is `preg-grep`?  There are *so many questions* about it, it would be great if there were some way for people who were actually good at it to answer them quickly, or our SO search which people love so dearly to pick up the tag from question content in auto suggestions.